# Convert array to dictionary (counter)

Tags: python

Suppose I have an `array` as follows

```
arr = [1 , 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I would like to convert it to a `dictionary` like

```
{
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1, 
  5: 1
}
```

My motivation behind this is so I can quickly increment the count of any of the keys in O(1) time.

Help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: If you use `Counter`, remember that this results in a Counter-object and not in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: 1 for k in arr}
```

Comment: Wrong answer, this will ALWAYS have "1" as count.

Comment: As far as I understood the question of OP, this step is to initialized the dictionary in order to increment the count in the future. Maybe we should leave the decision about the answer being wrong or correct, to the OP himself.

Comment: Hi guys. Yes I just wanted to initialize the dictionary so I could increment it later so this solution works well for me.

However I will also keep note of the `counter` functionality.

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import Counter
answer = Counter(arr)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [fromkeys](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_fromkeys.htm) method:

```
>>> arr = [1 , 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> dict.fromkeys(arr,1)
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
>>>
```

Comment: I hope a mistake... :D

Comment: Especially as OP asked explicitly for a dictionary and not an instance of some other class. Most answers are quite unrelated.

Comment: yes, I think people just want to introduce Counter collection to OP (it was my motivation at least)

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = Counter(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [**`collections.Counter`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> import collections
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> collections.Counter(arr)
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1 , 2, 3, 4, 5]
print({p: arr.count(p) for p in arr})
```

It's more precise I think and it still works when an element in the array repeats.